Body lost when PostAsJsonAsync() to an Azure Function endpoint
I have a test Azure Function end point defined as follows:
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "projects")] HttpRequestData req)
{

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
    {
        // Return bad request
    }
    
    // Do something

}

From the client app (ran via NUnit), if I call
var dtoClient = new DtoClient(p1, p2, etc);
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MyAzureFunctionPath", dtoClient);

I get a bad request.
If I call
var dtoClient = new DtoClient(p1, p2, etc);
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoClient), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/copilot/projects", content);`

I get a success.
Is PostAsJsonAsync broken? How is it possible that it does not work within the Microsoft ecosystem? I must be missing something.
I have read here that this is because the httpClient sets the content size to 0. So is this a bug? Should I simply avoid using PostAsJsonAsync or should I learn how to use it properly?

The PostAsJsonAsync creates a JsonContent under the hood. That class uses System.Text.Json's JsonSerializer. In your second example you are using Newtonsoft's Json.NET.

I would suggest to try to serialize your dtoClient both with System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft and compare the jsons to spot the differences.

My dtoClient is a POCO. I tried serializing with both and the output is the exact same.

Have you tried to create a JsonContent instead of StringContent and use the PostAsync?

@Ama PostAsJsonAsync isn't broken and doesn't do anything different from what you'd do. We have no idea what your actual DTO is. is a POCO says nothing. Does it have properties or public fields (major bug)? Are any properties read-only? Have you added column or type mappings, custom converters? Types that can only be mapped using JSON.NET but not System.Text.Json?

I tried the below HTTP trigger function code with the Test code using PostAsJsonAsync. The test cases passed successfully.
Code :
Function1.cs :
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("projects")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "projects")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Request body cannot be empty.");
            }
            var dtoClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DtoClient>(requestBody);
            return new OkObjectResult(dtoClient);
        }
    }

    public class DtoClient
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}

UnitTest1.cs :
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace FunctionApp2.Tests
{
    public class Function1Tests : IDisposable
    {
        private HttpClient _client;
        private TestServer _server;

        public Function1Tests()
        {
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(Function1).Assembly);
                })
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseRouting();
                    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapFunctionRoutes();
                    });
                });
            _server = new TestServer(builder);
            _client = _server.CreateClient();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task PostProjects_ReturnsOkResult()
        {
            var dtoClient = new DtoClient
            {
                Property1 = "Value1",
                Property2 = "Value2"
            };

            var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/projects", dtoClient);

            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            TearDown();
        }
    }

    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client1, string url1, T data)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return client1.PostAsync(url1, content);
        }
    }

    public static class EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void MapFunctionRoutes(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
            endpoints.MapPost("/projects", async context =>
            {
                string requestBody;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
                {
                    requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request body cannot be empty.");
                    return;
                }
                var dtoClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DtoClient>(requestBody);
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoClient));
            }).WithMetadata(new FunctionNameAttribute("projects"));
        }
    }
}

Postman Output :
I sent the post request with below json in the Postman as shown below,
{
"Property1": "Value1",
"Property2": "Value2"
}


Terminal Output :
The following HTTP trigger function code ran successfully as below,

Test case Output :
The following Test code ran successfully as below.


So the answer is that you can't reproduce the problem? We don't know what the DTO is yet, so any attempted test is bound to succeed simply because you wouldn't use a quirky DTO, eg one with public fields instead of properties.

The issue might be related to specific DTO structures or configurations. If you provide the exact DTO and any relevant details, I will check and update accordingly.
